# Using maintenance script to Reindex specific tables in a database

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

Is there a way I can use Maintenance solution to reindex specific tables in a database. I am dividing tables in my db to be large and small. Need to reindex large tables only on the weekend and others every day.

Comment: FWIW, index maintenance is mostly a wasteful operation not worth doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this manually (we have) by specifying the index names.  But you can do this as well by setting the MaxNumberOfPages or MinNumberOfPages as appropriate.

For example, your nightly job could have a MaxNumberOfPages set to a value that would exclude the "large" tables.  And then the weekend job would have no value set, letting it work on all the regular AND large tables.

If you specify the index (or table names) with a minus sign, Ola's script will ignore those objects.

See https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html for all the options and how to use them.